# Apache Wicket - Best way to update all components sharing a certain model

Tags: model, refresh, wicket

Using *Apache Wicket 9* - what is the best way for refreshing all *Component*'s sharing a *Model* whose content have been knowingly modified by a background process?

The following code works but I'm afraid that there is a better (built-in) solution I'm not aware of. Especially without calling *visitChildren*() for each *Model* with modified content:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <span wicket:id="child"></span><br>
    <a wicket:id="update">update</a><br>
</wicket:panel>

public class Test extends Panel {

    public Test(String id) {
        super(id);

        AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(); // arbitrary content within the model
        IModel<String> model = () -> i.toString();
        add(new Label("child", model).setOutputMarkupId(true));
        add(new AjaxLink<>("update") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                i.incrementAndGet(); // change content within the model
                updateComponents(target, model, getPage());
            }
        });
    }


    // for all components in page use root = getPage()
    public static void updateComponents(AjaxRequestTarget target, IModel<?> model, MarkupContainer root) {
        root.visitChildren(Component.class, (c, ivisit) -> {
            if (c.getDefaultModel() == model) target.add(c);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wicket does not provide anything related to this out of the box (in the latest version of the moment - Wicket 9.2.0).

Your implementation looks quite good to me! I'd do it the same way.

One improvement you could consider is to use AjaxRequestTarget.IListener that you could register globally, i.e. for the whole application, if you need the same logic in several places.

In MyApplication#init() method:

```
getAjaxRequestTargetListeners().add(new AjaxRequestTarget.IListener() {
  @Override public void onBeforeRespond(final Map<String, Component> map, final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    // map's values are the Components what you have already added to AjaxRequestTarget
    
    // I see your second approach:
    // You can use RequestCycle's MetaData to store flags which types
    // of components/behaviors/models need to be added to the target
    // as well. I.e. in #onClick() do
    // `RequestCycle.get().setMetaData(BEHAVIOR_TYPE, State2Listener.class)` 
    // and here use `Class<?> behaviorClass = `RequestCycle.get().getMetaData(BEHAVIOR_TYPE)`
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Could you please give me a short hint how I could use IListener to simplify things?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks again! See working implementation below :)

Answer (score 0):

Although my original approach is working I found that it is limited by the fact that components models must be designed to be suitable for comparison. To overcome this limitation I'd like to show another solution based on simple custom *Behaviors*. With this, we are able to accordingly refresh all required components without making any assumptions on the component models as shown in the following example:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <span wicket:id="child1"/> + <span wicket:id="child2"/> = <span wicket:id="sum"/><br>
    <a wicket:id="update1">update1</a><br>
    <a wicket:id="update2">update2</a><br>
</wicket:panel>

public class Test2 extends Panel {

    // example data class 
    static class Pojo implements Serializable {
        int i1, i2; // some mutable data
    }

    // data instance
    Pojo data = new Pojo();

    // listeners
    public class State1Listener extends Behavior {}
    public class State2Listener extends Behavior {}

    public Test2(String id) {
        super(id);
        
        add(new Label("child1")
                .add(new State1Listener()) // mark as depending on i1
                .setDefaultModel(() -> Integer.toString(data.i1))
                .setOutputMarkupId(true));

        add(new Label("child2")
                .add(new State2Listener()) // mark as depending on i2
                .setDefaultModel(() -> Integer.toString(data.i2))
                .setOutputMarkupId(true));

        add(new Label("sum")
                .add(new State1Listener()) // mark as depending on i1
                .add(new State2Listener()) // and i2
                .setDefaultModel(() -> Integer.toString(data.i1 + data.i2))
                .setOutputMarkupId(true));

        add(new AjaxLink<>("update1") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                data.i1++; // do some update on i1
                
                // we know that i1 was (potentially) modified,
                // so refresh all components depending on i1
                updateComponentsByBehavior(target, State1Listener.class, getPage());
            }
        });
        
        add(new AjaxLink<>("update2") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                data.i2++; // do some update on i2
                
                // we know that i2 was (potentially) modified,
                // so refresh all components depending on i2
                updateComponentsByBehavior(target, State2Listener.class, getPage());
            }
        });
    }
    
    // static helper method
    public static void updateComponentsByBehavior(AjaxRequestTarget target, Class<? extends Behavior> behaviorClazz, MarkupContainer root) {
        root.visitChildren((c, ivisit) -> {
            if (!c.getBehaviors(behaviorClazz).isEmpty()) target.add(c);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on martin-g's answer, here is another improvement of the latter *Behaviors* based approach. This time using *RequestCycle.get/setMetaData()* instead of repeatedly calling *visitChildren()*. To get the *Test2* example running with this setting, the calls of *updateComponentsByBehavior(...)* must be substituted with *registerComponentsByBehavior(...)*:

```
public class MyApplication extends WebApplication {

    private static final MetaDataKey<List<Class<? extends Behavior>>> BEHAVIOR_TYPE
        = new MetaDataKey<>() {};

    public static void registerComponentsByBehavior(Class<? extends Behavior> behaviorClazz) {
        // register behavior class in current cycle
        RequestCycle.get().getMetaData(WicketApplication.BEHAVIOR_TYPE).add(behaviorClazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        ...
        getRequestCycleListeners().add(new IRequestCycleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBeginRequest(RequestCycle cycle) {
                // clear list of registered behavior classes for current cycle
                RequestCycle.get().setMetaData(BEHAVIOR_TYPE, new ArrayList<>());
            }
        });
                
        getAjaxRequestTargetListeners().add(new AjaxRequestTarget.IListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBeforeRespond(final Map<String, Component> map,
                final AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                List<Class<? extends Behavior>> list =
                    RequestCycle.get().getMetaData(BEHAVIOR_TYPE);

                target.getPage().visitChildren((c, ivisit) -> {
                    for (Behavior b : c.getBehaviors()) {
                        // add components if behavior has been previously
                        // registered in current cycle
                        if (list.contains(b.getClass())) target.add(c);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Another small optimization: Use _HashSet_ instead of _ArrayList_ to store _Class_ instances may perform better in case that _registerComponentsByBehavior()_ will be called frequently for the same _Class_es.